# How to position an element aside to other using id/class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place the search element aside to the element "Media Heading 1" or "Media Heading 2" with respect to its id/class.

For example:

[image]

Consider, I have an element with class "media-item-1" and I want to place the search div aside to that element by using the its class "media-item-1". It should be dynamic in future I want to change the position by changing the target element id/class.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="media-item-1 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <div class="media">
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading 1</h4>
                This is some sample text. This is some sample text. 
                This is some sample text. This is some sample text.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>

<div class="sidebar-second">
    <div class="form-item-search col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <label for="search">Search</label>
      <input type="text" id="search"  size="15" maxlength="60">
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to do this using bootstrap/jquery?

Here is the code in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qodaxukuba/1/)

Comment: Change the top left of searchbox accroding to your `Media Heading 1` element using jquery and it will be placed by aside of that

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Set the div top of the element based on the specified id.

```
  <div class="sidebar-second" style="position:absolute;">
    <div class="form-item-search col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="width: 250px;">
      <label for="search" style="float:left;" >Search</label>
      <input type="text" id="search"  size="15" maxlength="60" style="float:left;">
    </div>
  </div>

 </div>
 <div><input type="button" value="SetMe" id="setme" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button"></div> 
 </div>

<script>
$( "#setme" ).click(function(){
   var setbutton = $( ".media-item-1" );
   var position = setbutton.position();
   $(".sidebar-second").css({top: position.top, left: 200, position:'absolute'});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zzjf3k8c/)

```
$("[class^='media-item-']:not(:last)").after($(".form-item-search").clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of putting two divs next to each other

```css
#class1 {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  }

#class2 {
  position:absolute;
  top: 10px;  
  left:220px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  }
```

```html
<div id="class1"> Div1 </div>
<div id="class2"> Div1 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4n6mq14d/